# Parsing CDATA string to XCDATA

Tags: c#, cdata

I have a string in CDATA format.
Eg:

```
string cdatastring = "<![CDATA[I am a string]]>";
```

I need to get the value inside the CDATA as a regular string by using inbuilt C# CDATA APIs. Something like below.

```
XCData cdataObject = (XCData)cdatastring;
string cdatavalue = cdataObject.value; //This should give me "I am a string"
```

Is there a way to do this?